# Debian repositories failing

Tags: debian

I have debian 8 installed.

When I try the commands sudo apt-get upgrade. Lots of errors like the following raise:

> E: Failed to fetch
>   http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-utils_2.8+dfsg-3~bpo8+1_amd64.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 99.86.122.111 80]

I have tried to change "/etc/apt/sources.list" but I couldnt find the right way to do it.

There are some other post in stack overflow about the same issue but none of them solved my problem. So please dont redirect me to other old post

Thanks in advance

Comment: try running `apt-get update` before running `apt-get upgrade`

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. Thanks

Comment: It has. Without `apt-get update`, your local package list is outdated, and apt tries to download files which no longer exist (therefore error 404). If you look into the URL of the error message, you'll see that the current version of qemu-utils on the server is 2.8+dfsg-6. The missing version 2.8+dfsg-3 is from 2017, and no longer on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the info from /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list to:

deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main

deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main